# Read ampersand as character UI router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In this state

```
state: 'someState',
        config: {
          url: '/:transactionId/:outerId?{notif:.*}',
          params: {
            transactionId: null,
            outerId: null,
            notif: null
          },
          ...
```

I put into URL state path like that

> ...?notif=firstPart&SecondPart

it return to $stateParams.notif only firstPart (stop at ampersand). I would like to catch into $stateParams.notif full string and handle & as a character.

Comment: Sounds like you should basically be escaping the `&`. Within an HTTP URL query parameter, `&` is the delimiter between key/value pairs. I suggest you accept that rather than fighting it.

Comment: use %26 to replace the ampersand: ?notif=firstPart%26SecondPart. If it's generated, use javascript escape() function to convert

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo `escape()` is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape